# Selecting a specific dropdown value based on how you navigated to a page

Tags: html, asp.net, web, navigation, dropdown

I've had a look around but not finding what I'm looking for, or I'm not searching for the right thing.

Language: ASP.NET

Basic idea of my problem:
2 pages - 1st page has 4 buttons, 2nd page has a dropdown box with 4 options.
If I press button 1 I want option 1 in the dropdown to be selected when I navigate, if I was button 2 then I want option 2 in the dropdown to be selected.

I still want to be able to change the value in the dropdown after navigation BUT the initial value should depend on which button I pressed.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I would use a querystring or a Session, depending on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You can transmit index of button via ViewBag. And in the 2nd page you set the property "selected" for the item which have the same index with value received from ViewBag.